# Convert a List<String> to Map<String, String> using the list values in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a List that I am trying to convert to a Map<String, String> using Java 8.

The list is as below

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("Name", "Sam", "Class", "Five", "Medium", "English")
```

I want a Map<String, String> such that the key value pair will be like

```
{{"Name", "Sam"}, {"Class", "Five"}, {"Medium", "English"}}
```

I am trying to achieve this in Java 8 and tried using Instream.range() but did not get the exact result.

```
IntStream.range(0, data.size() - 1).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> data.get(i), i -> data.get(i + 1)));
```

The issue with the above code is the result also gives an output as {"Sam", "Class"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

- generate a range of values, `i`, from `0 to size/2`.
- then use `i*2` and `i*2 + 1` as the indices into the list.

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("Name", "Sam", "Class",
        "Five", "Medium", "English");

Map<String, String> map = IntStream
        .range(0,data.size()/2).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> data.get(i*2),
                i -> data.get(i*2+1)));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Medium=English
Class=Five
Name=Sam
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're stepping through *every* index, whereas you just want to step through every other index. You could either filter the odd values, adding `.filter(i->i%2==0)` to your stream - or use `IntStream.iterate()` to get the numbers you want directly:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i->i<data.size()-1,i->i+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate every 2 elements, therefore the **steps** to do are
**3** equal to **6 (list size) / 2 (step size)**.

So iterate by steps and not by elements and you can find the two elements of each step in the collect phase. Here is the example:

```java
IntStream.range(0, data.size() / 2)
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> data.get(i * 2), i -> data.get(i * 2 + 1)));
```

Comment: How is that different from my answer?

Comment: The code is equal, the explanation is different. When I was writing the solution, I did not see that meanwhile you wrote a similar answer.